# How to align p tag to the left inside of a center tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to align a p tab that is inside of a center tag. Here is a part of my code:

```
<center>
    <div border="0" style="width: 640px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px;" valign="middle">
        <p style="width: 440px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; ">This text should be aligned left</p>
    </div>
</center>
<center>
    <div border="0" style="width: 640px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: middle; height: 60px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 30px;" valign="middle">
        <p style="width: 440px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 3px;">This text should be centered.</p>
        <a href="#">A URL </a>
    </div>
</center>
```

I cannot remove the center tag, but of course it can be improved. I am open for suggestion.

Comment: The center tag was an HTML 4 thing, it's 2021, don't use it.

Comment: @Love2Code you are definitely correct. This is like a template. I should either create my own using HTML5 or fix this. So, first, I try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<center>` tag that is not used anymore (HTML4 I thing). Add a class on your p and use the `text-align: center` css property (or div if you want to center everything in inside).

I removed the `style="width: 440px;"` from the `<p>` tag too.

```css
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div border="0" style="width: 640px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px;" valign="middle">
  <p style="width: 440px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; ">This text should be aligned left</p>
</div>


<div border="0" style="width: 640px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: middle; height: 60px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 30px;" valign="middle">
<p class="text-center" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 3px;">This text should be centered.</p>
<a href="#">A URL </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But here is the problem: some of the systems are not suitable with html5, so I need to keep html4 things. Thanks for your work

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to mark as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this: `style="text-align: left"`

Comment: Nop, this is not working. I already tried the well-known methods